# How to find if exist an uppercase character in string?

Tags: string, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, uppercase

I need to know if a string is at least one character or more. I need to find the `uppercase` character .

I used this code:

```
str testStr;
int flag;
testStr = "abdE2" ;

flag = strScan(testStr , "ABCDEFGHILMNOPQRSTUVZ" ,flag ,strLen(testStr));
info(strFmt("%1",flag) );
```

But not work!

A problem is that the function **strScan** does not distinguish uppercase and lowercase.

There is a solution?

Thanks,

Enjoy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code below tests if a string is one character or more and afterwards finds all the uppercase characters. Numbers are ignored since they cannot be uppercase.

```
static void findCapitalLetters(Args _args)
{
    str testStr = "!#dE2";
    int i;
    int stringLenght = strLen(testStr);
    str character;

    //Find out if a string is at least one character or more
    if (stringLenght >= 1)
    {
        info(strFmt("The string is longer than one character: %1",stringLenght));
    }

    //Find the uppercase character (s)
    for (i=1; i<=stringLenght; i+=1)
    {
        character = subStr(testStr, i, 1);

        if (char2num(testStr, i) != char2num(strLwr(testStr), i))
        {
            info(strFmt("'%1' at position %2 is an uppercase letter.", character, i));
        }
    }  
}
```

This is the output:

[image]

EDIT: Like Jan B. Kjeldsen pointed out, use `char2num(testStr, i) != char2num(strLwr(testStr), i)` and not `char2num(testStr, i) == char2num(strUpr(testStr), i)` to make sure it evaluates symbols and numbers correctly.

Comment: This does not work for non-alphanumeric characters. 
Better is to test for difference to lower case: `char2num(testStr, i) != char2num(strLwr(testStr), i)`

Comment: @JanB.Kjeldsen - Wow! Your right! I thought of numbers and used str2IntOk() to ignore them, but did not consider symbols like "!". If I understand it correctly the key is to test for NOT EQUALS, since a number or symbol's uppercase value is the same as it's lower case value. If you test that the uppercase and lower case values are not the same, you know that the character is a letter and not a number or symbol. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a job I wrote that shows 3 different methods of comparing strings with case sensitivity.  Just copy/paste/run.

```
static void Job86(Args _args)
{
    str a = 'Alex';
    str b = 'aleX';
    int i;
    int n;
    str     c1, c2;


    setPrefix("Compare");
    for (n=1; n<=strLen(b); n++)
    {
        c1 = subStr(a, n, 1);
        c2 = subStr(b, n, 1);

        if (char2num(c1, 1) == char2num(c2, 1))
            info(strFmt("Char2Num()\t%1 == %2", c1, c2));
        else
            info(strFmt("Char2Num()\t%1 != %2", c1, c2));


        if (strCmp(c1, c2) == 0)
            info(strfmt("strCmp()\t%1 == %2", c1, c2));
        else
            info(strFmt("strCmp()\t%1 != %2", c1, c2));

        i = System.String::Compare(c1, c2);

        if (i == 0)
            info(strfmt("System.String::Compare()\t%1 == %2", c1, c2));
        else
            info(strFmt("System.String::Compare()\t%1 != %2", c1, c2));
    }   
}
```